# iOS 6 Facebook Integration: How may I extract contacts from iPhone?

Tags: data-synchronization, contacts, ios, facebook

iOS 6 has a new feature that allows my facebook contacts to be synced as a separate group.
I would like to extract the contacts, is it possible to do somehow?

Comment: Do you have Mountain Lion?

Comment: Actually, it may work with Lion as long as your contacts sync with iCloud. Do you have Lion or Mountain Lion?

Comment: I do have Mountain Lion

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in the Contacts applications for OS 10.7+. First, you must set iCloud in System Preferences to sync your contacts, or you can sign into Facebook (if you're using Mountain Lion).

Then, open Contacts and select the "All Facebook" item to the left of the window. Select all visible contacts by clicking within the contact list and pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>.

Go to File > Export… > Export vCard… and save with the name and location you desire.

Comment: If one is using Windows, you can do the same things in iCloud.com. Sign in to iCloud.com, go to Contacts, select a group, select one contact, press Ctrl+A to select all contacts. Next, click on the Action button at the bottom of the web page, and click on "Export vCard."