# How to export address book to mailchimp or CSV file?

Tags: mac, contacts, csv

I want to export specific address book groups to mailchimp from a clients Mac computer.

The client have version OS X Lion (10.7) and the Mac she has is faulty and will be scrapped soon. Therefore it is not feasible to upgrade it.

It would be perfect if I could use [Chimport](https://itunes.apple.com/dk/app/chimport/id451733304?mt=12) but it appears that I need OS X Mountain Lion to use Apple Mac Store to get it.

Alternative do you know any programs that can export to CSV?

Comment: The Apple Store is working for OS X Lion as well (if that's really the OS version on your client's computer)

Comment: I will need to double check the version. Somehow I could not use Apple Mac Store

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66520/ios-6-facebook-integration-how-may-i-extract-contacts-from-iphone/68669#68669

Comment: Also you can copy and paste into Numbers.app. See this answer: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/191558/4160

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following AppleScript will [export all the names and e-mail addresses](http://theworklife.com/graham-miln/2014/03/31/exporting-contacts-to-csv/) from Contacts.app. It was written for OS X 10.9 but should work on older editions; you may need to change `Contacts` to `Address Book` to talk to the appropriate application:

To use this AppleScript:

1. Launch **AppleScript Editor** from Applications > Utilities
2. Copy and paste the code below into a new document
3. Run the script
4. On completion a `contacts.csv` will appear on your desktop

### Export Contacts to CSV AppleScript

```
-- Save comma separated values (CSV) file to desktop
set exportPath to (path to desktop as string) & "contacts.csv"

set contactsCSV to "" -- variable to collect rows of addresses
set quoteString to "\"" -- constant to ease concatenation

tell application "Contacts"

    -- Repeat with every person in your Contacts
    repeat with x from 1 to the count of people
        set thePerson to person x
        set theirName to the name of thePerson

        -- A person may have multiple e-mails addresses, add one row for each
        repeat with anEmail in the email of thePerson
            set contactsCSV to contactsCSV & quoteString & theirName & quoteString & "," & quoteString & (value of anEmail) & quoteString & "
"
        end repeat
    end repeat

end tell

-- Write the CSV contents to a file
set exportFile to open for access file exportPath with write permission
set eof of exportFile to 0
write contactsCSV to exportFile starting at eof
close access exportFile
```

Comment: If one wants to run this script on an older version of OSX where the Contacts app is called 'Address Book' - just change app name in this line like so: `tell application "Address Book"`

Comment: thanks so much for this script - it works!!

Comment: This produces broken CSVs if any name fieldss have quotes in them, such as 'Stan "The Man" Lee'.

Comment: @JohnSmith if you have contact details with quotes, see https://www.macscripter.net/t/dealing-with-strings-that-contain-double-quotes/66382/3 or manually fix the output if this is a one time task.

Answer (score 1):

Export your contacts as a VCARD bundle from Contacts.app and then import them into a [gmail](/questions/tagged/gmail) account which supports the VCARD format.  Once in Gmail, you can then export them as a [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) file.