# How to export Contacts version 9.0 data or .abbu file to .csv or other usable spreadsheet format

Tags: mac, contacts, numbers, csv

In the newest Apple Contacts version 9.0, how do you export all contacts or an .abbu file to a .csv file or other usable spreadsheet format? Dragging and dropping to Numbers does not work. Exporting to Vcard does not work...only exports a small handful of vcards out of over 4,000 and data is not usable in Numbers, Excel, or Outlook/Windows Live Mail. Please help!

Comment: See this related question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70281/how-to-export-address-book-to-mailchimp-or-csv-file

Answer (score 1):

Really simple:

- In Contacts select all contacts you want to export or press CMD-A.
- Press CMD-C (copy to clipboard).
- Open a new, empty Numbers document.
- Delete any existing table in that document.
- Press CMD-V to paste your clipboard.

This gives you a nice spreadsheet with all your selected contacts and proper rows and columns.

Comment: Works for me although I doesn't put everything in the right columns if a field is missing.

Comment: What do you mean by "if a field is missing"? If there's no entry of some sort in one of the contacts, while other contacts do have this entry?

Comment: Correct. For example if one contact has an image and another does not the row on the one that does not gets shifted so that the each cell is under the wrong column.

Comment: Sadly, this is true. As soon as you start using images, columns get shifted, even when there are no more images.

Answer (score 0):

In Contacts select all then Export as vCard file.

Use this [online conversion](http://labs.brotherli.ch/vcfconvert/) tool to get CVS file.

> vCard to LDIF/CSV Converter

You can also download the script and run in directly on your computer for increased privacy.

Comment: If your files re < 8mb else it won't work

Comment: Could you cite some reference as to why this might be the case?